# What are the problems of loading overlapping (or the same) tifs into postgis?

Tags: postgis, raster, postgresql

I am still early on the Postgis learning curve.  I have an existing table in Postgres - it looks like this:

```
create table "public"."mytable" (
  "rid" serial primary key,
  "rast" raster,
  "filename" text);
```

I have many tifs that I'd like to load into the table:

```
raster2pgsql -a -s 4326 -M -F -t 100x100  myfile.tif public.mytable > loadtif.sql
```

followed by (or as part of same step)

```
psql -d mydatabase -f loadtif.sql
```

I am curious to know how carefully I need to vet my tifs beforehand to make sure that they don't overlap at all.  Will there be a problem if they overlap with each other?  I notice that if I load the exact same `loadtif.sql` file multiple times, I get - as expected - a table with rows containing the same data loaded multiple times (though with different rids, of course).

This makes me think that overlapping tifs will indeed cause problems by causing duplicate row entries.  No?

Comment: Potential problems will arise primarily where the overlap does not contain data (like all black/white) and is not NoData (transparent). Other problems can arise where there are different dates (temporal change). It is possible to have the same raster loaded in several rows - so be careful the raster doesn't already exist before loading it or your database will blow out; this will not cause a problem with the functionality of the database but will waste space on your servers' discs.

Comment: Thanks, Michael.  Turns out my tifs overlap each other by one pixel on all sides.  Sounds like you're saying this shouldn't be a problem as far as database functionality goes.  Why is that?  I'm assuming the various ST functions somehow take overlap into account, though I would think there must be some functionality that could be compromised by overlap.  In any case - thanks!

Comment: It depends on what you're using them for, if you want to view them to make maps or capture from then the overlap is fine, even beneficial as it prevents white lines appearing at the tile joins. If you want to use them for analysis with respect to pixel count then the overlap *could* skew your results - normally though you would extract/export/classify the tiles into a single filesystem raster if this were the case and that would alleviate the overlap skew potential.

Comment: Thank you, Michael.  I want to use them for analysis, though not (as yet) pixel count.  More like for intersecting with other layers and doing a little spatial analysis.  For example, intersect raster with a layer of points and calculate neighborhood statistics for each point.  I think the overlap will be okay.  Postgis might not be the ideal tool for this, but it seems like it can handle large rasters and I've been wanting to learn it.